# Python build rpm from virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, rpm, setup.py

I created an rpm via `python setup.py bdist_rpm`.

The above command was called inside a virtualenv.

The files in the rpm now contain the absolute path to the virtualenv:

```
/home/user/...path-to-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

How to alter the paths? I want to install into `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `setup.cfg` file (create it if it doesn't exist) and add following section to it

```
[install]
install-lib=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Thank you. Where is the official documentation of setup.cfg and its parameters and sections?

Comment: The first problem was solved (I used prefix=/usr to change the path). But there is still something wrong: `rpm -qpR   dist/foo-1.0.4-1.noarch.rpm` requires: `/home/user/...path-to-virtualenv/bin/python` ... Help, how to solve this?

Comment: @guettli https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-rpm-packages Create a `.spec` file or use command-line option `--requires` (you can put this into `setup.cfg` too!).

Comment: @guettli Also I use Ubuntu and mine rpms do not require `python`. `(test)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-utopic-64:/tmp/requests-2.7.0$ rpm -qpR dist/requests-2.7.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1`